# Ldap SSH Login not working - Same configs worked on 20+ other servers - Ubuntu

Tags: ssh, pam, ldap, openldap

So I have setup LDAP Login on every server at my work successfully except one. Of course there has to be that one! And I want to close my jira ticket, but I can't figure out what the issue is. The system is a Ubuntu 10 x32

Here is the output of the auth.log

```
Oct 29 10:56:33 localhost sshd[2560]: Invalid user LDAPUSERNAME from 10.1.11.224
Oct 29 10:56:33 localhost sshd[2560]: Failed none for invalid user LDAPUSERNAME from 10.1.11.224 port 51830 ssh2
Oct 29 10:56:36 localhost sshd[2560]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Oct 29 10:56:36 localhost sshd[2560]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.1.11.224
Oct 29 10:56:36 localhost sshd[2560]: pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "uid=LDAPUSERNAME,ou=People,dc=DOMAIN,dc=com" (Invalid credentials)
Oct 29 10:56:38 localhost sshd[2560]: Failed password for invalid user LDAPUSERNAME from 10.1.11.224 port 51830 ssh2
```

UPDATE: This is a successfull login on another server and the output of auth.log

```
Oct 29 11:23:56 daily sshd[20625]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=10.1.11.224  user=LDAPUSERNAME
Oct 29 11:23:56 daily sshd[20625]: Accepted password for LDAPUSERNAME from 10.1.11.224 port 52211 ssh2
Oct 29 11:23:56 daily sshd[20625]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user LDAPUSERNAME by (uid=0)
```

Comment: Any chance this one server has a wrong time set?

Comment: I've got NTP setup on all servers locally

Comment: That IP was my local IP that I was trying to log in FROM, just FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason /etc/nslcd.conf was not created during installation. I copied it from another Ubuntu 10 Server which had working LDAP setup, but it wouldn't start because of the line >>

```
#nss_initgroups_ignoreusers ALLLOCAL
```

Which is odd, because its on the other Ubuntu 10 server, which I setup as well with the same configs, but thats linux. Regardless, (I commented it out) its working now!

Answer (score 1):

The authentication to the LDAP server is failing for some reason (not the authentication of the user):

> Oct 29 10:56:36 localhost sshd[2560]: pam_ldap: error trying to bind as user "uid=LDAPUSERNAME,ou=People,dc=DOMAIN,dc=com" (Invalid credentials)

How do you authenticate to the LDAP server, try to set `debug 9` to the `pam_ldap` line to get more information. Comparison with doing the same on the working server might bring some more ideas.

Also running manually `ldapsearch` can revel some errors in configuration.